# Azure DevOps Git Repository - not including all files in Changes

Tags: git, azure-devops

Made a new Azure DevOps Git repository. Moved over files from local TFVC repo. It is not including all the files - there is no .gitignore file.  Why is this?  In screenshot below it is not including Tfs2017Build.Lib.

[image]

In addition the folder mentioned, is also not including dependent DLLs.  Why is this?  I can see why typically don't want to have DLLs in repo but in this case we do.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the global file here that has those excluded:
"C:\Users{username}\Documents\gitignore_global.txt"